# Replacing texts tags to input field not working with replaceWith()

Tags: jquery, html, css

It is only a simple EDIT. I wanna change the headers, so If I am going to click the "edit" icon , then the header will change to a textfield and the "edit" icon will change to "save" icon.

```js
    
    $('#editheader').click(function(e){

        var category = $(this).closest("h3").text();        

        $( this ).replaceWith( "<a href=''> <i class='fa fa-save' aria-hidden='true' style='color:green'></i> </a>"  );
        $( this ).closest("h3").replaceWith( "<input value='" + category + "' >" );        

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="panel-title"> Letters To Investors
   <a href="#" id="editheader">
       <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green"></i>
   </a>
</h3>

<h3 class="panel-title"> Tax Documents
   <a href="#" id="editheader">
       <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green"></i>
   </a>
</h3>
```

Comment: I think this works. 
$(this).hide();
        $(this).closest("h3").hide();

        $('#editForm').show();

Answer (score 0):

I append a form in my html tag, and made this.

```
    $('#editheader').click(function(e){

        var category = $(this).closest("h3").text();   

        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest("h3").hide();

        $('#editForm').show();
        $('input[name=category]').val(category);     

        //$( this ).replaceWith( "<a href=''> <i class='fa fa-save' aria-hidden='true' style='color:green'></i> </a>"  );
        //$( this ).closest("h3").replaceWith( "<input value='" + category + "' >" );        

        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because replaceWith() removes the element you are refering to!
Just switch the lines to fix this issue.

```js
$('.editheader').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      let $h3 = $(this).closest("h3");
      let category = $(this).closest("h3").text();

      $h3.toggleClass('edit');

      if ($h3.hasClass('edit')) {
          const newCategory = $h3.children('input').val();
          $h3.children('input').remove();
          $h3.children('span').text(newCategory);
        } else {
          $h3.children('span').text('');
          $h3.prepend("<input value='" + category + "' >");

          $(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-pencil').addClass('fa-save');
        }
      });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="panel-title">
  <span>Letters To Investors</span>
  <a href="#" class="editheader">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green"></i>
  </a>
</h3>

<h3 class="panel-title">
  <span>Tax Documents</span>
  <a href="#" class="editheader">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green"></i>
  </a>
</h3>
```

Comment: but the button is gone. I want to make it to switch "save" button

Comment: Yeah, because replaceWith() removes everything inside `h3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your code this way:

- Don't use the same `id` for the buttons since ID must be unique change to classname
- Don't replace the `a` tag just change the class for the icon.
- Use a `span` to target easy the text of the `h3`
- Use a class as flag to know if it is edit or save

```js
$('.editheader').click(function(e) {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('save')){
    var category = $(this).siblings("span").text();
    $(this).siblings('span').replaceWith("<input value='"+category+"'/>");
   } else {
    var category = $(this).siblings("input").val();
    $(this).siblings('input').replaceWith("<span>"+category+"</span>");
   }
   $(this).toggleClass('save');
   $('i',this).toggleClass('fa-save fa-pencil');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="panel-title"> 
  <span>Letters To Investors</span>
  <a href="#" class="editheader">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green"></i>
  </a>
</h3>

<h3 class="panel-title"> 
  <span>Tax Documents</span>
  <a href="#" class="editheader">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green"></i>
  </a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, changing the parent element through the child is problematic. Solution is to put the text you want to change inside another placeholder element like **span** then replace it with the desired input element.

Another problem is replacing the element **a href** with another element while succeeding codes depends on the original element. Just changed the order of JQuery codes so it executes in logical order.

Lastly, the ids of the **a href** are the same. Use class instead.

```js
    
    $('.editheader').click(function(e){

        var category = $(this).closest("h3").text();        

$( this ).prev().replaceWith( "<input type='text' value='" + category + "' >" ); 
        $( this ).replaceWith( "<a href=''> <i class='fa fa-save' aria-hidden='true' style='color:green'></i> </a>"  );
               

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="panel-title"> <span>Letters To Investors</span>
   <a href="#" class="editheader">
       <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green"></i>
   </a>
</h3>

<h3 class="panel-title"> <span>Tax Documents</span>
   <a href="#" class="editheader">
       <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green"></i>
   </a>
</h3>
```